# Is it possible to create a performance counter on a remote Windows machine?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, performancecounter

Is there any way to programmatically create a performance counter on remote computer running Windows Server 2008?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly do it with [PSExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553). I don't know if there's an easier/cleaner way.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to "create an instance of an existing counter", or "register a new counter".

I'm not sure about registering a new counter remotely, but in managed code you can use [System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ffskxdc.aspx) to remotely create an instance of an existing counter.

Answer (score 1):

By using System.Diagnostics namespace it is not possible to create category on remote machine. You can use [WMI via .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx) which is exposed via System.Management and System.Management.Instrumentation namespaces.

Performance Monitor is attached to the one of the [WMI Provider for performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394570%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You could attach via WMI to remote machine to that provided and change values. Be aware about differences between Win OS versions.

You will need Administrative permissions to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, You cannot write to remote performance counters. There is no overload that allows you to specify a read/write instance of the PerformanceCounter class that connects to a remote computer. Refer the Note section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ffskxdc.aspx)